# cURL errors when run from shell script, but runs fine when run from terminal

Tags: shell, http, jenkins, curl

I'm running a command like this:

```
curl -H "<authentication>" -X PUT "<correct_path_on_server_side>" -T ./<local.file>
```

I am creating the command in a shell script, that is called in jenkins shell action, print it and run it.
It gives error :

```
curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

If I'm copying the printed out command - and paste it directly in jenkins shell action, when run the job it works fine. I have also tried to run it directly in terminal and also it works ok.

CURL was installed with "./configure --with-ssl" and when I type "curl -V" it returns both *http* an *https* in list of protocols.

What did I missed ?

Comment: You are not showing how you are quoting your URL. Is the actual URL in single quotes or double quotes: `'` or `"`?

Comment: ... and don't do `-X PUT` if you use `-T`...

Comment: I'm quoting with `"`. The upload path is created dynamically and contains shell variables. Using `"` was single solution found by me to interpret them.

Comment: `and don't do -X PUT if you use -T ` - could you please give more explanation? It works fine with both -X PUT and -T if I'm running from terminal or directly from jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

Run the `curl -V` command from inside the script that does not work.

Also run `which curl` and `ldd $( which curl )` from the same script.

Just to be sure, also dump the environment from both inside and outside the script, and compare them.

Chances are that the two installations don't load the same libraries (for example, the script might run inside a chrooted jail), or there is some such mishap.

Comment: `which curl`  and `curl --version` give the same output  if they from inside or outside the script.

Comment: Okay. Now you need to compare the `ldd` output and the output of `env` (or, worse, `set`) and look for clues there. The two program instances behave differently, so if they are identical, there **must** be a difference somewhere else - the libraries, the user, or their environment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.
It looks that the issue was related to the way I was calling the `curl` command inside the shell script.
I have tried with:

```
$my_curl_command
${my_curl_command}
exec $my_curl_commmand
eval $my_curl_command
/bin/bash ( or just bash if the PATH is set properly) $my_curl_command
"${my_curl_command[@]}"
```

I don't know why, but it works only in next cases:

- eval $my_curl_command
- bash $my_curl_command
- "${my_curl_command[@]}"

For the rest of them I got initial error:
`curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`